# Password Encryption Android, PHP

Tags: php, android, encryption, hash

## UPDATED:

I have my android app working fine with plain text password until now. I am trying to hash the password as next step. Cant find what the error is.

I am very sure that the communication is fine with plain text passwords.
I verified that the hashed value is getting stored in the DB properly(used varchar(80) for this attribute in the DB).

Please help.

Register.php

```
    <?php
include("config.php");

session_start();


// username and password sent from form 


$firstName = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST["firstName"]);

$lastName = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST["lastName"]);

$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST["email"]);

$myusername = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST["username"]);

$mypassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST["password"]); 

$passwordhash = password_hash($mypassword, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

$sql = "INSERT into user VALUES ('$firstName', '$lastName', '$myusername', '$email', '$passwordhash')";


$result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);


if($result) 
{

    echo "success";

}else{

    echo "failed";

}



?>
```

Login.php

```
    <?php
include("config.php");


session_start();



// username and password sent from form 

$myusername = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST["username"]);

$mypassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST["password"]);     

$sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = '$myusername'";

$result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);
$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$hash = $row['password'];

// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row



if(true === password_verify($mypassword,$hash)) {

    echo "success". "\n";  

    echo $row['firstName'] . "\n";

    echo $row['lastName'] . "\n";

    echo $row['username'] . "\n";

    echo $row['email'] . "\n";

}
else{

    echo " Incorrect Login. Please try again ";
}


?>
```

Comment: Don't call `password_hash()` again, instead use `password_verify()`

Comment: _"if there is a way in Android to encrypt"_ Just use SSL/TLS on the PHP side. _"that way I can directly query the DB without performing any encryption at the php level"_ Don't do that. You want the stored password to be hashed, never plain text.

Comment: See [section Alternative: Bcrypt Password Hashing in PHP](https://paragonie.com/blog/2016/02/how-safely-store-password-in-2016#php)

Comment: Yes. by "that way I can directly query the DB without performing any encryption at the php level" I mean that I want to encrypt the password in Android Application itself and send it over the internet. Not a plain text.

Comment: I just updated my error. Please revisit the query and help.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use password_verify($password, $hash) to verify the password. A new hash will use a different salt and result in a new value for the hash.

Comment: I just updated my error. Please revisit the query and help.

Comment: Even if the result is only one row you still need to get that row with $row[0]['password']

Answer (score 1):

you gotta use another php function called password_verify, it will verify that a particular password was used to create the hash.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php

Comment: you got anything that can help us? Error message? Or is it just returning false?

Comment: I am able to read the hash in the DB. And I am able to get that hash over to Android aswell. But I am not sure how to debug  the output of the Password_verify function.

Comment: I just updated my error. Please revisit the query and help.

Comment: Try this $passwordhash = password_hash($mypassword, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

Ive had issues with unexpected php hashing behavior. Using a specific hashing algorithm has helped.